# UncaughtTypeError products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, axios

product.map is not a function, i've tried almost all the fix from the web still not working. also, i've tried to console.log(response.data) and it response success

react ver 7.0

```
constructor () {
        super()
        this.state = {
          products: []
        };
      }
  componentDidMount(){
         axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products/1')
         .then(response => {
           this.setState({ products: response.data });
         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
         })
       }
  render(){
   var { products } = this.state;
    var merk = products.map(products =>  {products.merk} );
```

got error products.map is not a function at var merk=.....

thanks.

console.log:

```
{success: true, data: Array(1), message: "Phone retrieved Successfully.."}
data: Array(1)
0: {id_product: 1, merk: "Xiaomi ", tipe: "Mi Note 10", soc_nama: "Qualcomm", soc_tipe: "Snapdragon 855+", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Phone retrieved Successfully.."
success: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Is response.data returning an array for you?

Answer (score 2):

`products.map is not a function`, this mean `products` is not an array

In your API at componentDidMount, You have to access to the data that you return from server. You accessing to `response.data`, this mean you just access to the data of XMLHttpRequest, not data of your API.

Try to `console.log(response.data)`, and see which one is the array data that you want to get from server

Comment: how do i fetch it then? this is the console log                                                        {success: true, data: Array(1), message: "Phone retrieved Successfully.."}
data: Array(1)
0: {id_product: 1, merk: "Xiaomi ", tipe: "Mi Note 10", soc_nama: "Qualcomm", soc_tipe: "Snapdragon 855+", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Phone retrieved Successfully.."
success: true
__proto__: Object

Comment: Can you provide a console.log image ?

Comment: your products array is at response.data.data